# How to get class name from static method?

Tags: c++, qt, static

I'm programming with Qt5.9.  When in a NON static method I can get the class name using:

```
    metaObject->className();
```

Is it possible to get the class name when in a static method?

Comment: There is also a static meta object `const QMetaObject QObject::staticMetaObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QObject::staticMetaObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#staticMetaObject-var) should do the trick.

Comment: This returns "QObject", for my usage replace QObject with actual class name.

Comment: You can even leave the class name out when you call it in a static method of the same class. This notation is intended to point you to the class where it is implemented.